# How to Bulk update in HIbernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I need to update multiple rows in my MySQL database using Hibernate. I have done this using JDBC where we have the support of batched Query. I want something like this in hibernate.

Does hibernate support batched Query?

Batched query example in jdbc:

```java
// Create statement object
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

String SQL = "INSERT INTO Employees (id, first, last, age) " +
    "VALUES(200,'Zia', 'Ali', 30)";

// Add above SQL statement in the batch.
stmt.addBatch(SQL);

// Create one more SQL statement
String SQL = "INSERT INTO Employees (id, first, last, age) " +
    "VALUES(201,'Raj', 'Kumar', 35)";

// Add above SQL statement in the batch.
stmt.addBatch(SQL);

int[] count = stmt.executeBatch();
```

Now when we issue stmt.executeBatch call, both SQL queries will be executed in a single jdbc round trip.

Comment: Can you add the code you used for jdbc? I think that will be helpful.

Comment: Have you check the Hibernate documentation [for Batch processing](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch04.html)? What problems do you have?

Comment: Yes, @Jaime I have read hibernate docs, but I want the support of batched Which I am not able to find in the documentation.

Comment: Open the manual, Ctrl-F, batch, enter -> https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#batch. Why don't people just read the documentation?

Comment: I did not find any part where batched Query is discussed.@ JB Nizet

Answer (score 0):

You may check the [Hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#batch).  Hibernate has some configuration properties that control (or disable) the use of JDBC batching.

- If you issue the same `INSERT` multiple times and your entity does not use an identity generator, Hibernate will use JDBC batching transparently.
- The configuration must enable the use of JDBC batching. Batching is disabled by default.

---

**Configuring the Hibernate**

The `hibernate.jdbc.batch_size` property defines the number of statements that Hibernate will batch before asking the driver to execute the batch. Zero or a negative number will disable the batching.

You can define a global configuration, e.g. in the `persistence.xml`, or define a session-specific configuration. To configure the session, you can use code like the following

```java
entityManager
    .unwrap( Session.class )
    .setJdbcBatchSize( 10 );
```

---

**Using the JDBC batching**

As mentioned before, Hibernate call the JDBC batching transparently. If you wanna control the batching, you can use the `flush()` and `clear()` methods in the session.

The following is an example from the Documentation. It calls  `flush()` and `clear()` when the number of insertions reach a `batchSize` value. It works efficiently if `batchSize` is lesser or equal than the configured `hibernate.jdbc.batch_size`.

```java
EntityManager entityManager = null;
EntityTransaction txn = null;
try {
    entityManager = entityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();

    txn = entityManager.getTransaction();
    txn.begin();

    // define a batch size lesser or equal than the JDBC batching size    
    int batchSize = 25;

    for ( int i = 0; i < entityCount; ++i ) {
        Person Person = new Person( String.format( "Person %d", i ) );
        entityManager.persist( Person );

        if ( i > 0 && i % batchSize == 0 ) {
            //flush a batch of inserts and release memory
            entityManager.flush();
            entityManager.clear();
        }
    }

    txn.commit();
} catch (RuntimeException e) {
    if ( txn != null && txn.isActive()) txn.rollback();
        throw e;
} finally {
    if (entityManager != null) {
        entityManager.close();
    }
}
```